# Having trouble uploading larger files in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I started the last course of the Case Study. I started doing Case 1 from the Google Data Analytics Certificate with BigQuery SQL, but I am struggling to upload 202008 file because it is too much space **"Local uploads are limited to 100 MB. Please use Google Cloud Storage for larger files."**

Then I saw a video that I could reduce the size and save the excel file as Excel Binary Workbook (*.xlsb), but it still did not work. Did anyone face similar problems with Case 1 when uploading data? The error is when I changed the file from CVS to binary, which reduced the size from 93,213 to half of that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u09r.jpg)

Any help will be appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uclDw.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcWIJ.jpg)

Comment: You need to upload the file first to GCS and then to BigQuery from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to upload first the files to GCS, using preferably the gsutil, which allows you to use multipart to upload files, then you would be able to load it into BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the excel file to a csv and then upload it the google cloud storage and then upload it to BigQuery or else can also directly upload a local file to BigQuery for handling larger file sizes.

1. Navigate to Google BigQuery.
2. Create a new dataset or use an existing one.
3. Create a table and select type as csv and either browse local file or point to the file in GCS.
4. Make sure you give the header row value as 1 so the table considers the first row as your column headers.
5. Once uploaded you can view the table directly from BigQuery by clicking on the uploaded table and viewing details.